# BUSYBOX script is wrong

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to start script in busybox container which will outuput the date and words the busybox is running
when I'm up my compose file i just see that:

```
busybox_1 | tail: invalid number 'sh ./5sec.sh'
```

This is my script:

```
while true; do
sleep 5
date
echo busybox is running
done
```

It's my Dockerfile:

```
  FROM busybox:noauto
    COPY /5sec.sh /5sec.sh
    RUN chmod 777 5sec.sh
    CMD ./5sec.sh
```

It's my compose file (just in case)  :

```
version: '3'
services:
nginx:
image: "nginx:latest"
env_file: .env
ports:
- $HTTP_PORT:80
volumes:
- nginx-vol:/var/log/nginx
busybox:
image: "busybox:noauto"
volumes:
- nginx-vol:/var/log/nginx
volumes:
nginx-vol:
```

Help me please. How to start script automaticly. (Sorry for bad English)

Comment: I'm not sure where that error is coming from,  because you don't seem to be calling `tail` anywhere here.

Comment: If at some point you had both `build:` and `image:`, and the `image:` was the same as your Dockerfile `FROM` line, your later rebuilds would just be adding content on top of the previous image.  That could be one source of confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is this docker image `busybox:noauto` (probably your local image - build by you), and I guess this is reason of your problem. It's look like this image have some `RUN` command with `tail` or something like it.

I propose to use some standard busybox from dockerhub for your base image, for example `busybox:1`:

```
 FROM busybox:1
    COPY /5sec.sh /5sec.sh
    RUN chmod 777 5sec.sh
    CMD ./5sec.sh
```

Second question you should use `build` instead of `image` in you `docker-compose.yaml` if you want build image by yourself from your `Dockerfile`:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: "nginx:latest"
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - $HTTP_PORT:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-vol:/var/log/nginx
  busybox:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-vol:/var/log/nginx
```

This should solve your problem.

Notes:

- `chmod 777` isn't a good practice
- script should start with [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) - `#!/bin/sh` in your case